# Convert Arduino Code to STM32 cubeide,

Tags: arduino, stm32, uart, serial, stm32cubeide

I giving paramter setting of LoRa module which is [e32 433t20d][https://www.cdebyte.com/products/E32-433T30D] over the Arduino Nano with ebyte [RF setting software][https://www.cdebyte.com/pdf-down.aspx?id=1462]. With this code Arduino work as middleman. I want to use same code with stm32. How to make same code over the stm32 nucle board f401RE with Cubeide? It looks very easy but I really new one at cubeide. Please help thanks

Arduino Code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
 
SoftwareSerial fixSerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
 
#define M0 7
#define M1 6
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  fixSerial.begin(9600);
 
  pinMode(M0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M1, OUTPUT);
  
  digitalWrite(M0, HIGH);       // E32 Modülleri için Aktif edin
  digitalWrite(M1, HIGH);
}
 
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    fixSerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
 
  if (fixSerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(fixSerial.read());
  }
}
```

this is my first try but not succed.

```
while (1) {

    if (HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, rx1_data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) == HAL_OK) {
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, rx1_data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    }

    if (HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, rx2_data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) == HAL_OK) {
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, rx2_data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    }
```

All code:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
 ******************************************************************************
 * @file           : main.c
 * @brief          : Main program body
 ******************************************************************************
 * @attention
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
 * in the root directory of this software component.
 * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
 *
 ******************************************************************************
 */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include <string.h>

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

uint8_t rx1_data[1];
uint8_t rx2_data[1];

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
 * @brief  The application entry point.
 * @retval int
 */
int main(void) {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    /* USER CODE END 1 */

    /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

    /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
    HAL_Init();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

    /* USER CODE END Init */

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

    /* USER CODE END SysInit */

    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USART2_UART_Init();
    MX_USART1_UART_Init();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(M0_GPIO_Port, M0_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(M1_GPIO_Port, M1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

    /* USER CODE END 2 */

    /* Infinite loop */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (1) {

        if (HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, rx1_data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) == HAL_OK) {
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, rx1_data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        }

        if (HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, rx2_data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY) == HAL_OK) {
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, rx2_data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @brief System Clock Configuration
 * @retval None
 */
void SystemClock_Config(void) {
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = { 0 };
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = { 0 };

    /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
     */
    __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);

    /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
     * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
     */
    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
     */
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
            | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

/**
 * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void) {

    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

    /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
    huart1.Instance = USART1;
    huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
    huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

    /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
 * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void) {

    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

    /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
    huart2.Instance = USART2;
    huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
    huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

    /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
 * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void) {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = { 0 };

    /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

    /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, M1_Pin | M0_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /*Configure GPIO pin : LD2_Pin */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD2_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(LD2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /*Configure GPIO pins : M1_Pin M0_Pin */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = M1_Pin | M0_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
 * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
 * @retval None
 */
void Error_Handler(void) {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
    /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
    __disable_irq();
    while (1) {
    }
    /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is your expected behavior and what do you get instead? How have you attempted to troubleshoot the issue using a debugger?

Comment: the problem is stm32 and RF setting program not responding like arduino.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you're trying to do is some kind of serial bridge so that your STM will receive data from UART1 and send to UART2 and vice versa.

Do you really need it? why not just take some USB -> serial adapter and connect it directly.

Anyway, going back to your code the issue is in your loop, HAL_UART_Receive basically waits until at least 1 byte is available (with HAL_MAX_DELAY) so in your code you just wait first byte from UART1, send it to UART2 and then switch to receiving from UART2. What if 2 or more bytes will come from UART1? Only the first one will be received and you will hang up waiting HAL_UART_Receive on UART2. Hope you get the idea. So what you can do here is:

1. Use interrupts and setup you code in a way that the data will be expected from both UARTs simultaneously and then re-transmitted as it appears.
2. Do something like you do in Arduino example where you first check is data is available and then move on to the next UART. Without hanging up waiting data forever using HAL_UART_Receive with HAL_MAX_DELAY

Comment: nice ideas I am checking